# echo jquery in PHP syntax error - can't find my mistake

Tags: php, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

I try to echo out jQuery in PHP but it gives me following error whatever I do:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/login/application/controllers/sellercentral.php on line 309
```

The code:

```
echo '<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $("#Drafts > tbody:last").append('foreach($this->central as      $key2 => $value2) {
            '<tr> 
            <td><a href='. $value2->Token .'>Edit</a></td>
            <td class=T id='. $value2-    >Token.'>'.htmlentities($value2->Title).'</td>
            </tr>
        '.}.' );

                         });

            </script>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a foreach in a echo statement! Just break them up like this:

```
echo '<script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#Drafts > tbody:last").append(';

foreach($this->central as $key2 => $value2) {
    echo '<tr> 
            <td><a href='. $value2->Token .'>Edit</a></td>
            <td class=T id='. $value2-    >Token.'>'.htmlentities($value2->Title).'</td>
          </tr>';
}

echo  ');});</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an `echo` inside of your `foreach` loop. something like that :

```
echo '<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#Drafts > tbody:last").append(';

foreach($this->central as      $key2 => $value2) {
    echo '<tr> 
        <td><a href='. $value2->Token .'>Edit</a></td>
        <td class=T id='. $value2-    >Token.'>'.htmlentities($value2->Title).'</td>
        </tr>'; 
}
echo ' );
    });
</script>';
```