# Jquery syntax error Unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

I get the following error and don't know where my mistake is:

```
 Unexpected token <
```

Code (echo because of PHP used):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){$("#sellerDrafts > tbody:last").append(';
     foreach($this->view->sellercentral as $key2 => $value2)
     {
        echo '<tr><td><a href='. $value2->itemToken .'>Edit</a></td></tr>';}

        echo '});</script>';
```

Comment: `foreach($this->view->sellercentral as $key2 => $value2) {'` <- remove the single quote here

Comment: Do you really have a quote at the end of the `foreach` line?

Comment: sorry, the previous code was not the actual one ... it is still the same issue

Comment: Try to use this line in your foreach statement: `echo '<tr><td><a href="'. $value2->itemToken .'">Edit</a></td></tr>';` does this do the trick for you?

Comment: @Rizier123 same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [echo jquery in PHP syntax error - can't find my mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244054/echo-jquery-in-php-syntax-error-cant-find-my-mistake)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you do not have quotes `""` surrounding your append (and href), and it is not being closed with `);`.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$("#sellerDrafts > tbody:last").append("';
foreach($this->view->sellercentral as $key2 => $value2)
{
    echo '<tr><td><a href="'. $value2->itemToken .'">Edit</a></td></tr>';
}
echo '");});</script>';
```

On a side note, this is really not the best way to do this. A better way to do this would be to build it in PHP first then hand it off to your javascript. Like so:

```
<?php
   $table = "";
   foreach($this->view->sellercentral as $key2 => $value2)
   {
       $table = '<tr><td><a href="'. $value2->itemToken .'">Edit</a></td></tr>';
   }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sellerDrafts > tbody:last").append("<?php echo $table; ?>");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot the `echo` in the `append()` :*(